# Failing to enumerate over sections in object with JSONP and Mustache JavaScript templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, mustache

I am trying to enumerate and build the following fiddle with Mustache.js:

```
$(function () {
    var choices = { "users": [
        {    "first_name": "Ryan",
            "last_name": "Pays",
            "pic_square": "/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg",
            "product_name": "Merlin - the complete box set",
            "product_picture": "/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg"
        },
        {    "first_name": "Eric",
            "last_name": "Li Koo",
            "pic_square": "/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg",
            "product_name": "Merlin - Series 4 volume 1",
            "product_picture": "/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg"
        },
        {    "first_name": "Abdul",
            "last_name": "Raouf",
            "pic_square": "/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg",    
            "product_name": "Merlin - the complete box set",
            "product_picture": "/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg"
        }]
    };
    $.getJSON("http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/?callback=?", choices, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var template = "<ul>{{#users}}" +
                        "<li>" +
            "<p><strong>{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</strong> likes {{product_name}}</p>" +
                        "</li>" +
                        "{{/users}}</ul>",
            html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('.wrapper').html(html);
    });
});
```

Example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/mhMJA/3/

It correctly logs the JSON response to the console but then seems to be failing to build the template.  If i just pass a single user to the JSONP callback it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added your code to the question - jsfiddle is a great site but is sometimes very slow - its often better to include your code plus the jsfiddle example .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your fault. It's jsfiddle helps you convert your JSON object to the following format.

```
{"users[0][first_name]":"Ryan","users[1][first_name]":"Eric","users[2][first_name]":"Abdul","users[2][product_picture]":"/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg","users[1][product_picture]":"/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg","users[1][pic_square]":"/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg","users[1][product_name]":"Merlin - Series 4 volume 1","users[0][last_name]":"Pays","users[0][product_picture]":"/Global/products/full/box-set.jpg","users[1][last_name]":"Li Koo","users[0][product_name]":"Merlin - the complete box set","users[0][pic_square]":"/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg","users[2][last_name]":"Raouf","users[2][pic_square]":"/Global/profile/thumb/placeholder.jpg","users[2][product_name]":"Merlin - the complete box set","_":"1326530878282"}
```

I suggest you write your own JSONP app to avoid this issue. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/granjoy/mhMJA/7/) is I used [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to get the JSON object out.